# How to reveal Promise internal slot value with Proxy?

Tags: javascript, promise

I heard that there are some internal slots in the Promise instances.

```
[[PromiseState]] 
[[PromiseResult]] 
[[PromiseFulfillReactions]] 
[[PromiseRejectReactions]] 
[[PromiseIsHandled]]
```

There is no way to see their values. However there is a Proxy constructor in ES6 that helps to reveal values with get/set traps.

It is possible to do smth when we put some value in an ordinary object. But is it possible to do something when some value is put into [[PromiseResult]] internal slot?

Comment: No. A proxy intercepts property accesses, not arbitrary internal slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Internal slots might not even exist. They are a way of the spec to define the behaviour of JS internally. Engines don't have to implement these.

If your real question is "how to detect synchronously wether a promise resolved" ...

```
  function didResolve(promise) {
    let resolved; 
    promise.then(value => resolved = value);
    return function check() { return resolved; };
  }

  const task = Promise.resolve(42);
  const checker = didResolve(task);

  console.log(checker()); // undefined
  setTimeout(() => { console.log(checker()); /*42*/ });
```

Comment: If engines implement them, can they be revealed? Even if the behavior is non-standard, and possibly a bad idea; this might still be an interesting question to answer.

Comment: @evert yes, partly. Most browsers write parts of the codebase in JS that is able to call native functions via hooks. But regular code can't access these hooks, you have to explicitly tell the engine to allow that.